# How to draw framed rectangle in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

//ctx.arc(x,y,radius,startAngle,endAngle, anticlockwise);  

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.arc(100,100,100,0,Math.PI*2, false); // outer (filled)
ctx.arc(100,100,55,0,Math.PI*2, true); // outer (unfills it)
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

How can I achieve this effect with `ctx.rect()`? There does not seem to be a property similar to `anticlockwise` with `ctx.rect()`.

Comment: Maybe draw a smaller white rectangle over a larger black rectangle?

Comment: That would not achieve the same effect if there was something drawn on the canvas already.

Comment: This feels like you should just use a thick `stroke`, this is not really what rotation direction is meant for. It works, but if I see this code I will change it to a stroke, as its unclear what the outcome would be and it would be very similar to a stroke in general, making it too complex for its own good.

Comment: It is not the same because the inner circle can be positioned anywhere and be in any shape.

Comment: Well, it can be a circle, and that's it. And you could use a buffer to generate your different layers if this is necessary, then write them onto a canvas. In short, no such a thing does not exist for `rect` because you are using it in a way that's unintentional, just a consequence of calculations. Also, if you wanted a non-stroke response, at least make it look like the circle is offset so we know it's not just a stroke. Your example is confusing.

Comment: This post says it is possible. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030069/how-to-draw-segment-of-a-donut-with-html5-canvas

"The same would work if you were drawing a "framed" rectangle. You draw a box one way (clockwise), then draw the inner box the other way (counter-clockwise) to get the effect." Is this not done with ```ctx.rect()``` but with something else? Or is this post wrong?

Comment: Okay I'll be honest, it is possible because of how the winding algorithm is intended to be used, so let me take that back. I tried it in my answer and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not with the `rect` method. If you manually implement a clockwise anti-clockwise rectangle it can work, see below:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const size = 200;

canvas.width = canvas.height = size;

// Just to show that the content still comes through
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, size, size );

ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

ctx.beginPath();

// Clockwise Rectangle
ctx.moveTo( 10, 10 );
ctx.lineTo( 190, 10 );
ctx.lineTo( 190, 190 );
ctx.lineTo( 10, 190 );
ctx.lineTo( 10, 10 );

// Anti-Clockwise Rectangle
ctx.moveTo( 20, 20 );
ctx.lineTo( 20, 180 );
ctx.lineTo( 160, 180 );
ctx.lineTo( 160, 20 );
ctx.lineTo( 20, 20 );

ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

This is only true because of the winding algorithm. You could probably implement a method yourself that allows for clockwise or counter clockwise, you don't get that for free in canvas.

### Clarification

The reason for this is the fill-rule property, which you can pass in to `.fill`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill, so it will work on any reversed path with the default `nonzero` rule.

@je3rdty This works with any path that reverses, including ellipses, because of the fill rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const size = 200;

canvas.width = canvas.height = size;

// Just to show that the content still comes through
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, size, size );

ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.ellipse( 100, 100, 100, 75, 0, 0, Math.PI * 2, false );
ctx.ellipse( 100, 100, 80, 50, Math.PI / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true );
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: How can I do the same thing with ```ctx.ellipse()```? https://jsfiddle.net/tu1pmv6z/ It works with ```ctx.arc()``` but not ```ctx.ellipse()```. http://jsfiddle.net/Hnw6a/8/

Comment: @je3rdty It should work on any path method that can be reversed, like ellipse, whose last argument is a counter clockwise boolean. This is because the filll gets determined by 'winding order': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number

Comment: I used ```ctx.ellipse()``` in the same way as ```ctx.arc()``` but it did not work.

Comment: @je3rdty It does, you must have made a mistake. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: @je3rdty Also, the article linked is more generally about the mathematical idea, this on is more about the system specifically: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule - it's quite interesting.